# ASP.net MVC Razor View Logic locked during debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not able to edit the code within logic blocks inside the razor views despite Edit and Continue being on.  HTML sections of the file are still editable, but anything within the @ blocks is locked until Debugging is stopped.

Setup details:

- VisualStudio 2013
- MVC 5.1
- Using IISExpress locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be the result of the Roslyn preview I had installed.  After removing the preview, the files were fully editable, as they have always been.

I haven't looked into it much, but I believe this is a result of the views being compiled into the assemblies by the separate Roslyn compiler.